# new line in react admin textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I do I make the TextField recognize a new line with the "\n" because when I to enter it in the Field it's just print it as it is

```
<TextField source="body" component="pre"/>
 Just Try to post to many stuff not relevent\nand think he is a god
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I found the solution and it just add multiline and its fix the problem